# Is a creature aware that a Hex or Hunter's Mark spell has been cast on it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Both spells have a verbal component when casting them, but they can both be cast from 90 feet away, possibly from stealth or while the creature is distracted, so it may not notice the casting.

I'm sure the creature would feel the disadvantage to the chosen ability from Hex (would feel/be clumsier if Dexterity is chosen, or short of breath and tired if Constitution is chosen, etc), but might not know the cause. And would an actual mark appear on the target if Hunter's Mark is cast on it?

Would they maybe need to pass an Arcana check (or passive check, maybe) to discern/notice what's affecting them?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

PHB p 204

> Unless a spell has a perceptible effect, a creature 
>   might not know it was targeted by a spell at all. An effect 
>   like crackling lightning is obvious, but a more subtle 
>   effect, such as an attempt to read a creature’s thoughts, 
>   typically goes unnoticed, unless a spell says otherwise.

So, yes, they remain unaware.